# If statement in a template only run the first if-statement - QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

```
template <class T> void IOcalibrationWindow::setChildIntoIOcalibrationObject(int i, QString firstChildName, QString lastChildName, QString firstIocalibrationMethodName, QString lastIOcalibrationMethodName){
    /* Get the index as string */
    QString index = QString::number(i);

    /* Create the UI field name */
    QString childName = firstChildName + index + lastChildName;

    /* Create the object name */
    const char *IOcalibrationMethodName = (firstIocalibrationMethodName + index + lastIOcalibrationMethodName).toLatin1().data();

    /* Get UI child */
    T *uIchild = findChild<T*>(childName);

    /* Get calibration object */
    const QMetaObject *IOcalibrationMetaObject = iOcalibration.metaObject();

    /* Insert into object */
    if(std::strcmp(T::staticMetaObject.className(), "QDoubleSpinBox") != 0)
        IOcalibrationMetaObject->invokeMethod(&iOcalibration, IOcalibrationMethodName, Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(double, uIchild->value()));
    else if(std::strcmp(T::staticMetaObject.className(), "QLineEdit") != 0)
        IOcalibrationMetaObject->invokeMethod(&iOcalibration, IOcalibrationMethodName, Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(QString, uIchild->text()));

}
```

This is an if-statement in QT where I'm accessing the specific method inside object `iOcalibration`. The method name is called `IOcalibrationMethodName`.

Sometimes the method `IOcalibrationMethodName` has an argument of `double` or `QString`.
It all depends on the template `T`, which can be `QDoubleSpinBox` or `QLineEdit`.

When I call the function, you can see that I'm using different templates.

```
setChildIntoIOcalibrationObject<QDoubleSpinBox>(i, "analogSingleInput", "MaxDoubleSpinBox", "setAnalogSingleInput", "Max");
setChildIntoIOcalibrationObject<QDoubleSpinBox>(i, "analogSingleInput", "MinDoubleSpinBox", "setAnalogSingleInput", "Min");
setChildIntoIOcalibrationObject<QLineEdit>(i, "analogSingleInput", "UnitLineEdit", "setAnalogSingleInput", "Unit");
```

**Problem:**

My problem with the code is that when I using the template class `QLineEdit`, I get an error at this code line.

```
IOcalibrationMetaObject->invokeMethod(&iOcalibration, IOcalibrationMethodName, Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(double, uIchild->value()));
```

This should not be possible due to the `if-statement`.
The error is:

```
iocalibrationwindow.cpp:102:133: error: no member named 'value' in 'QLineEdit'
qobjectdefs.h:95:51: note: expanded from macro 'Q_ARG'
iocalibrationwindow.cpp:80:9: note: in instantiation of function template  
specialization 'IOcalibrationWindow::setChildIntoIOcalibrationObject<QLineEdit>' 
requested here
```

That means, that the first `if-statement` runs when I'm using template `QLineEdit`.
But the if-statement checks if the template is `QDoubleSpinBox`

```
if(std::strcmp(T::staticMetaObject.className(), "QDoubleSpinBox") != 0)
```

**Question:**

How can this be possible that `QLineEdit` till be equal as `QDoubleSpinBox`?

Comment: The compiler doesn't run your code, it just compiles it. It's true that at runtime that code should never be hit with the wrong type of object, but the compiler cannot know that so it must be valid on all code paths at compile time.

Comment: @RetiredNinja so, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but, from the code that's given, why can't you simply split out the `uIchild->*` calls into a couple of functions overloads?  That would result in something like (untested)...

```
QGenericArgument fetch_data (QDoubleSpinBox *p)
{
  return Q_ARG(double, p->value());
}

QGenericArgument fetch_data (QLineEdit *p)
{
  return Q_ARG(QString, p->text());
}

template <class T> void IOcalibrationWindow::setChildIntoIOcalibrationObject(int i, QString firstChildName, QString lastChildName, QString firstIocalibrationMethodName, QString lastIOcalibrationMethodName){
    /* Get the index as string */
    QString index = QString::number(i);

    /* Create the UI field name */
    QString childName = firstChildName + index + lastChildName;

    /* Create the object name */
    const char *IOcalibrationMethodName = (firstIocalibrationMethodName + index + lastIOcalibrationMethodName).toLatin1().data();

    /* Get UI child */
    T *uIchild = findChild<T*>(childName);

    /* Get calibration object */
    const QMetaObject *IOcalibrationMetaObject = iOcalibration.metaObject();

    /* Insert into object */
    if(std::strcmp(T::staticMetaObject.className(), "QDoubleSpinBox") == 0)
        IOcalibrationMetaObject->invokeMethod(&iOcalibration, IOcalibrationMethodName, Qt::DirectConnection, fetch_data(uIchild));
    else if(std::strcmp(T::staticMetaObject.className(), "QLineEdit") == 0)
        IOcalibrationMetaObject->invokeMethod(&iOcalibration, IOcalibrationMethodName, Qt::DirectConnection, fetch_data(uIchild));

}
```

[Note that I've changed the sense of the `if (strcmp(...` comparisons: [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) returns zero if the strings are equal.]

Comment: these two functions solved my problem! Thank you.